# Subconsulta en linq

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2014

Tengo la siguiente consulta de sql server que tiene una subconsulta

```
SELECT  periodo, tipo, tipoDia, p
  FROM  registrar.tiempoPeriodo tp
     where frtID='hkt00010' and periodo >= '2019-11-10'
          and tp.tipo in ('ValorTipicoInicial', 'ValorTipico ')
          and tp.periodo = (select MAX(vers.periodo)
              from registrar.tiempoPeriodo vers
              where vers.frtID = ct.frtID
              and vers.tipoDia = ct.tipoDia)
```

Y en mi linq tengo la consulta al que llevo a un List<>

```
var list = context.ObtenerObjetos<tiempoPeriodo>();

            ListResult = (from e in list
                          where e.Periodo >= FechaConsulta &&
                                e.Tipo.Contains("ValorTipicoInicial") ||
                                e.Tipo.Contains("ValorTipico")
                          select new CurvaTipicaTO
                          {
                              FrtID = e.FrtID,
                              Periodo = e.Periodo,
                              Tipo = e.Tipo,
                              TipoDia = e.TipoDia

                          }
           ).ToList();
```

pero en esta ultima no tiene subconsulta, como se haria esto en linq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta, fue algo asi:

```
ListResult = (from e in list
                      where e.Periodo >= FechaConsulta &&
                            e.Tipo.Contains("ValorTipicoInicial") ||
                            e.Tipo.Contains("ValorTipico") &&
                            e.Periodo == ( list.Where(b => b.FrtID == e.FrtID)
                              .Max(b => b.Periodo) )
                      select new CurvaTipicaTO
                      {
                          FrtID = e.FrtID,
                          Periodo = e.Periodo,
                          Tipo = e.Tipo,
                          TipoDia = e.TipoDia

                      }
```

Fuente otra pregunta parecida en [stackoverflow en Ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15361890/subquery-with-linq)